# How to use reverse url within app to point to a template of a different app?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have two apps: simulation_api and building_data. Each one has templates and urls. The urls I import in my main configuration.

In my template of simulation_api I would like to set a link to my detail view of building data.

This is what I am trying (in my template of simulation_api) which throws me an error (`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch`):

```
{% for item in simulations.project.buildinggroup_set.all %}
               <a href="{% url "detail_building_group" item.id %}">{{ item.description }}</a>
 {% endfor%}
```

The for loop works, the problem is the url that I am trying to reverse.

I am reversing it like this in my models of building_data:

```
class BuildingGroup(models.Model):
    name           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    project               = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("detail_building_group", kwargs={"id" : self.id})
```

I think the problem is somehow that I reverse the url in one app but it is not recognised in the template of the other app. But maybe it's also something else...

Anyone has an idea? Thanks so much in advance! Very much appreciated!

Not sure if it is useful, but here my simplified model for the simulation:

```
class Simulation(models.Model):
    project                 = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my urls of building_data

```
app_name = 'buildings'
urlpatterns = [
    path('list/building-group/<int:id>/', DetailBuildingGroupView.as_view(), name="detail_building_group"),

]
```

My traceback:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail_building_group' not found. 'detail_building_group' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 66, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 81, in get_response
response = self._middleware_chain(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/app/analytics/middleware.py", line 22, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 158, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in _get_response
response = response.render()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
content = template.render(context, self._request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
return self.template.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 98, in instrumented_test_render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 98, in instrumented_test_render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 67, in render
result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 447, in render
url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 90, in reverse
return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 636, in _reverse_with_prefix
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail_building_group' not found. 'detail_building_group' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it doing this:

I added a namespace to my urls in my main config.

Then I reversed it like this:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("buildings:detail_building_group", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

whereas `buildings` is my namespace and `detail_building_group`is my url-name.

Also I had to add my detail-url to my other app as well in the urls, so it recognized the url.

Thanks JPG for leading me in the right direction!

This also helped: http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2016/01/06/django-how-to-reverse-urls-belonged-to-other-apps